# oci_fetch_array fetch out of sequence

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I have problem for show array data from Oracle Database to table HTML.

This is the query :

```
$sql ="SELECT A.AC,A.CREATED_BY,A.SCHEDULE_COMPLETION_DATE FROM WO A, SECURITY_HEADER B WHERE A.AC LIKE 'PK%' AND A.CREATED_BY=B.\"USER\" AND B.ADOPT_USER_PROFILE LIKE 'MAINT%' AND A.STATUS!='CLOSED' AND A.SCHEDULE_COMPLETION_DATE BETWEEN '$tgl_awal' AND '$tgl_akhir' AND (A.SCHEDULE_COMPLETION_DATE-SYSDATE)<0 ";

$sql_statement = OCIParse($connect,$sql);

OCIExecute($sql_statement);
```

This is table code

```
<thead>
            <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
            <th class="text-center">AC</th>
            <th class="text-center">CREATED BY</th>
            <th class="text-center">USER PROFILE</th>
            <th class="text-center">SCHEDULE COMPLETION DATE</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>

            <?php

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($sql_statement,OCI_BOTH)){
//$no++;

?>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th class="text-center"><font size="2"><?php echo $row['AC']; ?></font></th>
            <th class="text-center"><font size="2"><?php echo $row['CREATED_BY']; ?></font></th>
            <th class="text-center"><font size="2"><?php echo $row['ADOPT_USER_PROFILE']; ?></font></th>
            <th><font size="2"><?php echo $row['SCHEDULE_COMPLETION_DATE']; ?></font></th>

            </tr>
            </tbody>

            <?php                

}

oci_free_statement($sql_statement);
oci_close($connect);

?>

</table>
```

This is a notice :

```
oci_fetch_array() [function.oci-fetch-array]: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence in C:\xampp\htdocs\graph\pages\work_orderf3.php on line 544
```

Line 544

> while ($row = oci_fetch_array($sql_statement,OCI_BOTH)){

Comment: i think the error comes from the sql statement try to run this query in your database first and try to echo $sql variable and check the $sql string

Comment: echo $sql; exit;

Comment: when i tried sql statement in sql developer it's running. so it means sql statement has no problem @MinaRagaie

Comment: ok just print the value of $sql

Comment: like this echo $sql; exit;

Comment: and then copy the the printed value and try to run it in your  sql developer

Comment: Okee..Thank you very much

Comment: fetch out of sequence means that you are trying to read data from a cursor after the cursor has returned the last row. You have to detect when there are no more rows in your while loop and exit the loop.